# How to show locations in Simile Exhibit Map?

Tags: javascript, html

**Task:** I have a Google Spreadsheet with dates and locations. I want to show these data on a Simile Timeline and on a Google map. The page has space for both. The dates are shown on the Timeline, but the locations don't appear on the map. What do I have to do in order to solve this?
This is the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/escolaportuguesaunion.org/spreadsheets/d/1eL_g5nC0spoBGgPAy98rJVMXWxzizek9u0SRtTJocnU/pubhtml) public link.

Here goes the Html header:

```
<script src="http://api.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/3.1.0rc/exhibit-api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://api.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/3.1.0rc/extensions/time/time-extension.js"></script>

  <link rel="exhibit-extension" 
        href="http://api.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/3.1.0rc/extensions/map/map-extension.js?service=google2&gmapKey=ABQIAAAA5JLLfCE9c7HAtg25QM2KCRRyiP6mHEsQpwvxB19-hS9Kgd8RYhSXEtJVAXDUCZPqwtZZi7-HUYUYrw" 
        type="text/javascript" />

  <script src="http://api.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/3.1.0rc/extensions/map/map-extension.js"></script>

  <link     
        rel="exhibit/data" 
        type="application/jsonp"
        href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1eL_g5nC0spoBGgPAy98rJVMXWxzizek9u0SRtTJocnU/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script"
        ex:converter="googleSpreadsheets" />
```

And the body:

```
<div ex:role="view"
     ex:viewClass="Timeline"
     ex:start=".start"
     ex:end=".end"
     ex:topBandUnit="decade"
     ex:bottomBandUnit="century"
     ex:colorKey=".eventType"
     ex:timelineheight="200">
  </div>

  <center ex:role="logo" ex:color="DimGrey"></center> 
  <div ex:role="lens">
     <b ex:content=".label"></b>
     <p><img ex:if-exists=".image" ex:src-content=".image" width="150"/></p>
     <p ex:content=".description"></p>
     <p ex:content=".eventType"></p>
     <div ex:if-exists=".location">Localização: <span ex:content=".location"></span></div>
  </div>
 <div ex:role="view"
     ex:viewClass="GoogleMaps2"
     ex:label=".label"
     ex:latlng=".latlng"
     ex:center="38.5707742, -7.9092808"
     ex:zoom="5" >         
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locations were not appearing on the map for a simple reason. On the spreadsheet column header 
I wrote {latlng.location }, 
Instead of {latlng:location }.
The script doesn’t recognize “.”, it will only recognize “:”.
For this reason I’ll close the question.